# how to find derivative

Tags: maple

It is necessary for me to find $\Delta^2 u=u_{xxxx}+u_{yyyy}+2u_{xxyy}$ where $u=u(r,t).$

I tried by the following but got an error in Maple.

$$x:=rcos(t);~y:=rsin(t);$$
then tried to find
$$diff(u,x$4)+diff(u,y$4)+2diff(diff(u,x$2),y$2).$$

but there was an error, what is the problem? how can I find this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simpler way is

```
L:= D[1,1]+D[2,2]:
PDEtools:-dchange({x= r*cos(t), y= r*sin(t)}, (L@@2)(u)(x,y), simplify);
```

Comment: @ carl love, thank you, but can you explain a little what did you do? what is L and L@@2?

Comment: **L** is the Laplacian operator. **L@@2** means to apply the operator to itself. **D[1,1]** means the second derivative with respect to the first variable. Let me know if you need more explanation.

Comment: @ carl love, thank you, that was enough.

Answer (score 2):

First the Laplacian can be written as
$$
\Delta = \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}
=\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}.
$$
Then the biharmonic opeartor $\Delta^2$ is the square of the Laplacian,
$$
\Delta^2 u = \left(\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}\right)^2 u=
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} u
+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} 
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}u
+\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial t^2}
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}r\frac{\partial}{\partial r} u
+\frac{1}{r^4}\frac{\partial^4}{\partial t^4}u.
$$

---

You have to use the package PDEtools in MAPLE to do change of variables.

`restart;
with(PDEtools)
PDE := diff(u(x, y),`$`(x, 4))+diff(u(x, y),`$`(y, 4))+2*(diff(diff(u(x, y),`$`(x, 2)),`$`(y, 2)));
tr := {x = r*cos(t), y = r*sin(t)}
eq := dchange(tr, PDE)
simplify(eq)`